# Converting several factors from one column to binary for presence/absence binary in R

Tags: r

I want to compare beta species richness, and to do this I want to convert my current data to presence/absence binary code to use in the R betapart program.

I have two columns - the first with a site location where species were sampled, and the second is a column with ALL fish species observed (18+ species in some cases). Below is an example of what I am working with:

---

```
#Site        Species
#0001-HIL    yellow bullhead, brown bullhead, goldfish
#0001-ETC    yellow bullhead, goldfish, emerald shiner
#0001-BAP    brown bullhead, emerald shiner
```

---

I would like to use appropriate R code to take the above data.frame and turn it into a matrix this:

```
           #yellow bullhead___brown bullhead___goldfish___emerald shiner
#0001-HIL         1                 1             1              0
#0001-ETC         1                 0             1              1
#0001-BAP         0                 1             0              1
```

(Forgive the use of all the #, I could not create a table otherwise).

I know about use of reshape, sapply, melt, etc. but I really have no clue which to use. I have just over 10,000 rows of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

We can easily do after `split`ing the 'Species column

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$Species), ","))
row.names(d1) <- df1$Site
d1
#          brown bullhead  emerald shiner  goldfish brown bullhead
#0001-HIL               1               0         1              0
#0001-ETC               0               1         1              0
#0001-BAP               0               1         0              1
#         yellow bullhead
#0001-HIL               1
#0001-ETC               1
#0001-BAP               0
```